# Play audio when hovering image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few images on my page and when I hover over them they should each play a certain sound. Also, I don't want audio players to be visible.

I tried this but it only works when I click on audio player before hovering image:

**HTML**

```
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src = "Pkokoska.jpg" onmouseover="playSound1()"></a>
<a href="Okonj.html"><img src = "Pkonj.jpg" onmouseover="playSound2()"></a>

<audio controls id="audio1"><source src="Zkokoska.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<audio controls id="audio2"><source src="Zkonj.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

function playSound1() {
sound1.play();
}

function playSound2() {
sound2.play();
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the audio files are loaded? Maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: No , its because he is missing the `controls` attribute in audio tag

Comment: @SandrinJoy, I tried doing it with it, but it only works if I click on that player before hovering the image.

Comment: ok i will check it

Comment: and it works for me btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to add `controls` attribute in the audio tag to activate the controlling functions such as play , plause ,etc.. for that element**

```
     <audio controls id="abc> ... </audio>
```

*You can also hide the controls tab by ussing css property `dsiplay:none`*

```js
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

function playSound1() {
sound2.pause();
sound2.currentTime = 0;
sound1.play();
}

function playSound2() {
sound1.pause();
sound1.currentTime = 0;
sound2.play();
}
```

```css
audio{
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45" onmouseover="playSound1()"></a>

<audio id="audio1" controls><source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/wav"></audio>

<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45" onmouseover="playSound2()"></a>

<audio id="audio2" controls><source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

Comment: A single function could work the same as if multiple ones are used?

Comment: yes , with a single function we can do the same. But i don't know which will be efficient

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work on pure javascript but am sure it will with JQuery

```
function playSound1() {
  sound1.trigger('play');
}


function playSound2() {
  sound2.trigger('play');
}
```

Comment: check what i did with jquery -- 
`<audio src="" class="audio"></audio>`

`function audioPlayer(audio) {
    $('.audio').attr('src', '../static/audio/'+audio).trigger('play');
  }audioPlayer('windows.mp3')`